# How to continue a framed box which is defined in floating environment

Tags: floats, xetex, environments, mdframed

I have defined a floating environment. It defines a framed box using \mdframe. Here is the code I used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{float}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={!ht},name=Frame]{myfloat}

\begin{document}
\begin{myfloat}[tb]
\begin{mdframed}
\caption{Lipsum Frame}

\lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\end{myfloat}


\end{document}
```

The text content in the mdframed box is too large to fit in a single page. But on executing this code, I miss the text content which exceeds the first page's limit. The framed box abruptly stops at the end of first page. How to continue my framed box on the next page?

Comment: Floating objects cannot be broken.

Comment: If you need a caption, you can use `\captionof{myfloat}{Actual caption content}` (without the actual *floating wrapper*)